# Removing comments with a sliding window without nested while loops

Tags: c, sliding-window

I'm trying to remove comments and strings from a c file with c code. I'll just stick to comments for the examples. I have a sliding window so I only have character `n` and `n-1` at any given moment. I'm trying to figure out an algorithm that does not use nested `whiles` if possible, but I will need one while to `getchar` through the input. My first thought was to while through find when `n=* and (n-1)=/` then while through until `n=/ and (n-1)=*`, but considering this has nested whiles I feel it is inefficient. I can do it this way if I have to, but I was wondering if anyone had a better solution.

Comment: Try to formulate a state machine. I.e. when ever you encounter a character '*' or '/' or '\' or '"' or a single quote, you update your `state` depending on your previous state. (Nasty examples can btw. split a comment separator `*/` to multiple lines: `*\/n/`)

Comment: A state machine is probaly the best way to conceptualise this. You will probably have four states: `normal`, `normal-seen-slash`, `comment` and `comment-seen-star` when processing `/* foo */` style C comments.

Comment: Do you have to handle trigraphs?  Do you have to handle backslash-newline in between the `/` and `*` of a start comment (or between the `/` and `/` of a C++ style comment, or the `*` and `/` at the end of a C style comment)?  Do you have to handle backslash-newline at the end of a C++ style comment?  Do you handle multi-character character constants such as `'/*'` which does not start a comment?  Obviously, `"/*this is not a comment*/"` is not a comment; it is a string saying that it is not a comment.  (Rather like Magritte and his "Ceci n'est pas un pipe" pictures — Google it.)

Comment: Look here: http://www.bdc.cx/software/stripcmt/

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm written with one `while` loop could look like this:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    ... // looking at the byte that was just read

    if (...) // the symbol is not inside a comment
    {
        putchar(c);
    }
}
```

To decide whether the input `char` belongs to a comment, you can use a state machine. In the following example, it has 4 states; there are also rules for traversing to next state.

```
int state = 0;
int next_state;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    switch (state)
    {
        case 0: next_state = (c == '/' ? 1 : 0); break;
        case 1: next_state = (c == '*' ? 2 : c == '/' ? 1 : 0); break;
        case 2: next_state = (c == '*' ? 3 : 2); break;
        case 3: next_state = (c == '/' ? 0 : c == '*' ? 3 : 2); break;
        default: next_state = state; // will never happen
    }

    if (state == 1 && next_state == 0)
    {
        putchar('/'); // for correct output when a slash is not followed by a star
    }
    if (state == 0 && next_state == 0)
    {
        putchar(c);
    }
    state = next_state;
}
```

The example above is very simple: it doesn't work correctly for `/*` in non-comment contexts like in C strings; it doesn't support `//` comments, etc.

Comment: I will eventually expanding this to do strings, characters and // comments as well.

Answer (score 2):

Doing this correctly is more complicated than one may at first think, as ably pointed out by the other comments here. I would strongly recommend writing a table-driven FSM, using a state transition diagram to get the transitions right. Trying to do anything more than a few states with case statements is horribly error-prone IMO.

Here's a diagram in dot/graphviz format from which you could probably directly code a state table. Note that I haven't tested this at all, so YMMV.

The semantics of the diagram are that when you see `<ch>`, it is a fall-though if none of the other input in that state match. End of file is an error in any state except `S0`, and so is any character not explicitly listed, or `<ch>`. Every character scanned is printed except when in a comment (`S4` and `S5`), and when detecting a start comment (`S1`). You will have to buffer characters when detecting a start comment, and print them if it's a false start, otherwise throw them away when sure it's really a comment.

In the dot diagram, `sq` is a single quote `'`, `dq` is a double quote `"`.

```
digraph state_machine {
    rankdir=LR;
    size="8,5";

    node [shape=doublecircle]; S0 /* init */;
    node [shape=circle];

    S0  /* init */      -> S1  /* begin_cmt */ [label = "'/'"];
    S0  /* init */      -> S2  /* in_str */    [label = dq];
    S0  /* init */      -> S3  /* in_ch */     [label = sq];
    S0  /* init */      -> S0  /* init */      [label = "<ch>"];
    S1  /* begin_cmt */ -> S4  /* in_slc */    [label = "'/'"];
    S1  /* begin_cmt */ -> S5  /* in_mlc */    [label = "'*'"];
    S1  /* begin_cmt */ -> S0  /* init */      [label = "<ch>"];
    S1  /* begin_cmt */ -> S1  /* begin_cmt */ [label = "'\\n'"]; // handle "/\n/" and "/\n*"
    S2  /* in_str */    -> S0  /* init */      [label = "'\\'"];
    S2  /* in_str */    -> S6  /* str_esc */   [label = "'\\'"];
    S2  /* in_str */    -> S2  /* in_str */    [label = "<ch>"];
    S3  /* in_ch */     -> S0  /* init */      [label = sq];
    S4  /* in_slc */    -> S4  /* in_slc */    [label = "<ch>"];
    S4  /* in_slc */    -> S0  /* init */      [label = "'\\n'"];
    S5  /* in_mlc */    -> S7  /* end_mlc */   [label = "'*'"];
    S5  /* in_mlc */    -> S5  /* in_mlc */    [label = "<ch>"];
    S7  /* end_mlc */   -> S7  /* end_mlc */   [label = "'*'|'\\n'"];
    S7  /* end_mlc */   -> S0  /* init */      [label = "'/'"];
    S7  /* end_mlc */   -> S5  /* in_mlc */    [label = "<ch>"];
    S6  /* str_esc */   -> S8  /* oct */       [label = "[0-3]"];
    S6  /* str_esc */   -> S9  /* hex */       [label = "'x'"];
    S6  /* str_esc */   -> S2  /* in_str */    [label = "<ch>"];
    S8  /* oct */       -> S10 /* o1 */        [label = "[0-7]"];
    S10 /* o1 */        -> S2  /* in_str */    [label = "[0-7]"];
    S9  /* hex */       -> S11 /* h1 */        [label = hex];
    S11 /* h1 */        -> S2  /* in_str */    [label = hex];
    S3  /* in_ch */     -> S12 /* ch_esc */    [label = "'\\'"];
    S3  /* in_ch */     -> S13 /* out_ch */    [label = "<ch>"];
    S13 /* out_ch */    -> S0  /* init */      [label = sq];
    S12 /* ch_esc */    -> S3  /* in_ch */     [label = sq];
    S12 /* ch_esc */    -> S12 /* ch_esc */    [label = "<ch>"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you only wish to use two characters for the buffer and only one while loop, I would suggest a third char to track your state (whether skipping text or not). I've put together a test program for you with inline comments explaining the logic:

```
// Program to strip comments and strings from a C file
//
//  Build:
//     gcc -o strip-comments strip-comments.c
//
//  Test:
//     ./strip-comments strip-comments.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* The following is a block of strings, and comments for testing
 * the code.
 */
/* test if three comments *//* chained together */// will be removed.
static int value = 128 /* test comment within valid code *// 2;
const char * test1 = "This is a test of \" processing"; /* testing inline comment */
const char * test2 = "this is a test of \n within strings."; // testing inline comment
// this is a the last test


int strip_c_code(FILE * in, FILE * out)
{
   char      buff[2];
   char      skipping;

   skipping = '\0';
   buff[0]  = '\0';
   buff[1]  = '\0';

   // loop through the file
   while((buff[0] =  fgetc(in)) != EOF)
   {
      // checking for start of comment or string block
      if (!(skipping))
      {
         // start skipping in "//"  comments
         if ((buff[1] == '/') && (buff[0] == '/'))
            skipping = '/';

         // start skipping in "/*"  comments
         else if ((buff[1] == '/') && (buff[0] == '*'))
            skipping = '*';

         // start skipping at start of strings, but not character assignments
         else if ( ((buff[1] != '\'') && (buff[0] == '"')) &&
                   ((buff[1] != '\\') && (buff[0] == '"')) )
         {
            fputc(buff[1], out);
            skipping = '"';
         };

         // clear buffer so that processed characters are not interpreted as
         // end of skip characters.
         if ((skipping))
         {
            buff[0] = '\0';
            buff[1] = '\0';
         };
      };

      // check for characters which terminate skip block
      switch(skipping)
      {
         // if skipping "//" comments, look for new line
         case '/':
         if (buff[1] == '\n')
            skipping = '\0';
         break;

         // if skipping "/*" comments, look for "*/" terminating string
         case '*':
         if ((buff[1] == '*') && (buff[0] == '/'))
         {
            buff[0]  = '\0';
            buff[1]  = '\0';
            skipping = '\0';
         };
         break;

         // if skipping strings, look for terminating '"' character
         case '"':
         if ((buff[1] != '\\') && (buff[0] == '"'))
         {
            skipping = '\0';
            buff[0]  = '\0';
            buff[1]  = '\0';
            fprintf(out, "NULL"); // replace string with NULL
         };
         break;

         default:
         break;
      };

      // if not skipping, write character out
      if ( (!(skipping)) && ((buff[1])) )
         fputc(buff[1], out);

      // shift new character to old character position
      buff[1] = buff[0];
   };

   // verify that the comment or string was terminated properly
   if ((skipping))
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "Unterminated comment or string\n");
      return(-1);
   };

   // write last character
   fputc(buff[1], out);

   return(0);
}


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
   FILE * fs;

   if (argc != 2)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <filename>\n", argv[0]);
      return(1);
   };

   if ((fs = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
   {
      perror("fopen()");
      return(1);
   };

   strip_c_code(fs, stdout);

   fclose(fs);

   return(0);
}

/* end of source file */
```

I've also posted this code on Github to make it easier to download and compile:

https://gist.github.com/syzdek/5417109