# c - Removing comments (/* and //) and strings

Tags: c

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with the following code that's suppose to remove comments and strings from an input (but not comments that's why it recognizes comments)? This is related to a prior question of mine: [Removing comments with a sliding window without nested while loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086617/removing-comments-with-a-sliding-window-without-nested-while-loops)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c, c1 = 0, c2 = 0 ,state = 0, next = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        switch(state)
        {
           case 0: next = ((c2 == '*' && c1 == '/') ? 1 : (c2 == '\"') ? 2 : (c2 == '/' && c1 == '/') ? 3 : (c2 == '\'') ? 4: 0); break; 
           case 1: next = ((c2 == '/' && c1 == '*') ? 0 : 1); break; 
           case 2: next = ((c2 == '\"' && c1 != '\\') ? 0 : 2); break;
           case 3: next = ((c2 == '\n') ? 0 : 3); break;
           case 4: next = ((c2 == '\'' && c1 != '\\') ? 0 : 4); break;
           default: next = state; 
        }
        c = getchar(); if( c < 0) break;
        c1 = c2; c2 = c; // slide window
        if(state == 1)
        {
            if(c2 == '*')
            {
                c = getchar();
                c1 = c2; c2 = c;
                if(c2 != '/')
                   putchar(c1);
            }
            else
                putchar(c2);
        }
        else if(state == 2)
        {
            if(c2 != '"' || (c2 == '\"' && c1 != '\\'))
                putchar(c2);
        }
        else if(state == 3)
        {
                putchar(c2);
        }
        else
        state = next;
        // c2 is the current input byte and c1 is the previous input byte
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: make the state some `enum` and choose good names for each state....

Comment: Can you give an example of some input it's failing to process correctly?

Comment: You have written your code so unreadably as to be unmaintainable. If you can't read and understand how it works, then you cannot diagnose later faults/needs for improvement in it.

Comment: What's wrong with it? It doesn't handle trigraphs *or* line splices correctly!

Comment: I can't seem to get the /* comments to work. When I take out the if statement for `state == 1` the // comments and strings work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you actually need a sliding window for your task of removing C and C++ comments.  You can expand your state machine to include a few additions states for tracking escapes, etc...  With more states the code gets a bit bigger, but it *might* make it conceptually simpler since you only have *one* state to track.  So converting the spirit of your code to the new state machine formula I'd suggest, you get the code below (and I also agree with Basile's suggestion of using enums and included it).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    enum {
        START, SLASH,
        STRING, CHAR, STRING_ESCAPE, CHAR_ESCAPE,
        SINGLE_LINE_COMMENT, MULTI_LINE_COMMENT, MULTI_LINE_END,
    } state = START;
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        switch (state) {
        case START:
        state_START:
            if (c == '/') { state = SLASH; break; }
            putchar(c);
            if (c == '\"') state = STRING;
            else if (c == '\'') state = CHAR;
            break;
        case SLASH:
            if (c == '/') state = SINGLE_LINE_COMMENT;
            else if (c == '*') state = MULTI_LINE_COMMENT;
            else { state = START; goto state_START; }
            break;
        case STRING:
            putchar(c);
            if (c == '"') state = START;
            else if (c == '\\') state = STRING_ESCAPE;
            break;
        case CHAR:
            putchar(c);
            if (c == '\'') state = START;
            else if (c == '\\') state = CHAR_ESCAPE;
            break;
        case SINGLE_LINE_COMMENT:
            if (c == '\n') state = START;
            break;
        case MULTI_LINE_COMMENT:
        state_MULTI_LINE_COMMENT:
            if (c == '*') state = MULTI_LINE_END;
            break;
        case STRING_ESCAPE:
            putchar(c);
            state = STRING;
            break;
        case CHAR_ESCAPE:
            putchar(c);
            state = CHAR;
            break;
        case MULTI_LINE_END:
            if (c == '/') state = START;
            else { state = MULTI_LINE_COMMENT; goto state_MULTI_LINE_COMMENT; }
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The reason why I used a sliding window is because it is a homework assignment and my professor told us to.

Answer (score 0):

just to give you an advice without knowing your purposes... Did you thought about regular expressions to solve your problem? It is may faster and your code will be cleaner, assuming you understand regular expressions.

I found a neat site for your problem by the way... It explains how to get those comments out of the code...

[How get comments with regex](http://ostermiller.org/findcomment.html)

And [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/regex.htm) is a library for regex in C.

Comment: Can you put up some examples and explain how regular expressions apply to this question?  Answers are not supposed to __just__ link to other resources, they are supposed to have all explanation self contained (linking to outside sources is still a good thing though).

Comment: @milleniumbug Nobody here is attempting to parse (generate a syntax tree of) C. Regular expressions is a perfectly valid approach to recognizing C string literals and comments, and is a good way to do scanning (tokenizing) of C source. (That's what [flex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_(software)) does)

Comment: Well the homework assignment had us do it in lex and c, so I figured since I used regular expressions in lex I should do something else for the c code.