# K&R exercise 1-23 remove comments

Tags: c

I am stuck on this exercise. I can't figure out why the following code doesnt have the desired result. 
 The program is supposed to remove comments. In this program I don't take strings and/or character literals into account. Also, just for test purposes i put spaces instead of NULL at points that need be removed.

Here are two tests:

 test /* test123 ok test */
**generates to:** 
 test  * test123 ok test */

doesnt //work 
 **generates to:**

doesnt    ork

Also, if the input is too big I get a segmentation fault

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLENGTH 1000

void removec(char code[],int length);

int main()
{
    int i, c;
    char line[MAXLENGTH];


    for(i=0; (c = getchar()) != EOF; i++)
        line[i] = c;

    removec(line, i);
return 0;
}

void removec(char line[], int l)
{
    int i;

    for(i=0; i < l; i++){
        //printf("%c", line[i]);
        if(line[i] == '/' && line[i+1] == '/'){
            while(i != '\n'){
                line[i] = ' ';
                ++i;
            }
        }
        else if(line[i] == '/' && line[i+1] == '*'){
            while((line[i] != '*') && (line[i+1] != '/')){
                line[i] = ' ';
                ++i;
            }
        }

    }
    printf("%s", line);
}
```

Comment: I think the limit `i < l` are not being taken into account when the `++i`

Comment: The list of related questions (on the right) has good links; for example, [Removing comments and strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105194/c-removing-comments-and-and-strings?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first section of code has a typo:

```
        while(i != '\n'){
```

It should be

```
        while(line[i] != '\n'){
```

The second section of code has slightly incorrect logic:

```
        while((line[i] != '*') && (line[i+1] != '/')){
```

The right logic can be expressed correctly in several ways; try rewriting it in the following form:

```
        while (!(blah blah blah)) {
```

where `blah blah blah` is the condition you want to check.

Please also note that if the comment is not terminated (e.g. no new-line character after `//`), your code will try to read data beyond the end of the input file (causing bad output or crash). To fix this, add the check `i < l` to all conditions in `while` loops.

Answer (score 1):

You have two separate issues going on here. The line

```
while(i != '\n')
```

needs to be

```
while(line[i] != '\n')
```

As written, your loop condition is going to evaluate whether `i` is equal to the decimal value of the newline character, which happens to be 10. So it's only going to go up to `line[9]`, which explains why you're getting the output

```
doesnt ork
```

as in the input, `line[9]` is the `w` of `work`.

With the second conditional, you have a logic problem:

```
while((line[i] != '*') && (line[i+1] != '/'))
```

won't work. Here is what is going on.

1. The else condition is true: `line[i]` is `'/'` and `line[i+1]` is `'*'`.
2. `line [i]` is not `'*'` and `line[i+1]` is not `'/'`, so the `while` loop begins to execute
3. `line[i]`, i.e., the `'/'`, is replaced by a space
4. `i` gets incremented
5. `line[i]` is now the `'*'` (which used to be `line[i+1]` before the increment)
6. The `while` condition fails, because `line[i] != '*'` is false; `line[i]` is indeed `'*'`
7. The `while` loop terminates, and you're left with `test * test123 ok test */` as your output.

Make sense?